# Multi go instance share one public channel

Tags: go, kubernetes

I have an implementation about a channel which will keep there are an only limited number of tasks(20) in this channel due to some performance issue. **(The performance issue is from an outside system, this system can not handle more than 20 tasks at the same time)**.

Now I want to move this logic to a microservice on Kubernetes, the problem is that the replica of pod number will change to an unknown number. So I cannot set the channel length to a specified number to control the total number. Is there a way to cover this case that I can use one public channel for multi go instance? Or some other lights about this case? Thanks.

========================supplementary instruction=======================

I have an api in my microservice, which will call an outside system api to handle some operations. The outside system api can only handle 20 concurrency and currently I can not fix it because it is out of my control. So I implemented a channel in my project(single instance) which will handle this case. For example, if 30 request come in at the same time, I will put 20 of them to the channel and 10 request waiting. If the request in the channel completed one by one and the left 10 request will go to the channel one by one.  Now comes to the multi instance case and I encountered this problem.

Comment: why dont you create a service for this microservice and use that service as your entry point.

Comment: Sorry, just add some instructions with black font.  The performance issue is from outside system. So create service can not limit the total quest number to the outside system at the same time if there are unknown number of pods.

Comment: Can you explain scenario? What kind of task this microservice does when it communicate with this outside system (is it going to update database, update cache 
 etc) ?

Comment: (Assuming your service doesn't have persistency) your service can use the etcd distributed key value store or something similar to keep the number of connections and deny requests when already at 20 connections. Or you add persistency to your service, e.g. use a CockroachDB in your cluster which has transactional guarantees.

Comment: Why does the replica of the pods change to an unknown number? Why can you just keep it fixed?

Comment: @Rico there is an auto-scale policy which may change the number of pods from 2 to more

Comment: @OswinNoetzelmann Thanks, I will investigate about the "transactional guarantees", we hava a mongodb in our project. Hopes it could help. And I dont want to drop the additional request which is more than 20.

Comment: @Keaz just add the supplementary instruction in the description. Thanks